# composer-install of Drupal8 creates a tmp####/ folder. How to manage & clean it?

Tags: installation, configuration, composer, files

I'm working with Drupal, with v8, using Composer to install & manage it.

I create a new Drupal8 project using the 'drupal-composer/drupal-project' template,

```
composer create-project --keep-vcs --stability dev --no-interaction drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev mysite
```

That installs

```
tree mysite  -L 1
    mysite
    ├── composer.json
    ├── composer.lock
    ├── drush
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── phpunit.xml.dist
    ├── README.md
    ├── scripts
    ├── tmp12972441691459034756
    ├── vendor
    └── web
```

If you look inside that 'tmp#' folder

```
tree mysite/tmp12972441691459034756 -L 2
    mysite/tmp12972441691459034756
    └── drupal-8.0.5
        ├── autoload.php
        ├── composer.json
        ├── composer.lock
        ├── core
        ├── example.gitignore
        ├── index.php
        ├── LICENSE.txt
        ├── modules
        ├── profiles
        ├── README.txt
        ├── robots.txt
        ├── sites
        ├── themes
        ├── update.php
        ├── vendor
        └── web.config
```

it looks like a complete copy of the source.

Afaict, it's used only on the first install, and doesn't ever seem to get cleaned up or deleted (by cron etc).

Do I need to keep those files around for some reason?  Or is it safe to just delete that folder?

Is there a Drupal8 maintenance task, maybe cron, that should be cleaning it out?

I've read older comments on this, and there's references to old versions' "/tmp" usage, but this is not that I guess, and this has a hash.  Anyway, I don't see the Drupal8-specific usage instructions anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't keep the tmp folder. The scaffolding plugin should delete tmp folder after it copied the necessary files into the web folder. Not sure what went wrong on your machine.

Fixed in https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold/issues/33

Comment: ok, thanks.  I did try the composer install on a couple different machines, and it's always the same here -- /tmp# is created and sticks around.

Comment: Please open a bug report on https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project. I hope we can fix the bug, please share some info about your system configuration. Thanks!

Comment: It's there now, https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/issues/133